# Transposing in quadratic forms (example: Lyapunov equation)

Tags: proof-verification, lyapunov-functions

I'm wondering why the Lyapunov equation is derived as follows:

Consider in the System
$$\dot{x}=Ax$$
The following Lyapunov Function is chosen
$$V(x)=x^TPx$$
where
$$\dot{V}(x)=\dot{x}^TPx+x^TP\dot{x}$$
follows. Using the first equation delivers
$$\dot{V}(x)=x^T(A^TP+PA)x=-x^TQx$$

Because I can transpose a quadratic form, I could also write the following
$$\dot{V}(x)=2\dot{x}^TPx=2x^TA^TPx$$

Which would mean that $2A^TP = -Q$ but I suppose that's nonsense. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So $P$ is symmetric but $A$ is not?

Comment: How did you derive the last two equations?

Comment: @Ian yes, exactly.

Comment: @copper.hat Which ones do you mean? Like I said, I can transpose quadratic forms, hence, $(\dot{x}^TPx)^T=(x^TP\dot{x})$

Comment: I get $x^T(P+P^T)Ax$ and I have no idea how you conclude that $2A^TP = -Q$.

Comment: $A^TP$ is not symmetric. That's the problem. Note that for non-symmetric $A$ you can have $x^TAx = 0$ for all $x$ although $A\neq 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat It's ok. As OP wrote: $x^TP\dot x = (x^TP\dot x)^T = \dot x^TPx$.

Comment: @amsmath this means, that I have to plug in $\dot{x}=Ax$ before I transpose the expression?

Comment: No, your computations are fine. Please read my updated comment.

Comment: How do you obtain $2A^TP = -Q$??? You are pulling this out of thin air.

Comment: @copper.hat I commented on that already. OP concluded from $x^TBx = 0$ that $B=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat I derived $\dot{V}(x)$ in two different ways and then I simply compare them and see, that there must be a mistake in my second way. $$\dot{V}(x)=x^T(A^TP+PA)x=-x^TQx=\dot{V}(x)=2\dot{x}^TPx=2x^TA^TPx$$

Comment: @copper.hat Please read my comments. I wrote exactly what you wrote.

Comment: I seem to be in an infinite loop. It is true that $x^T(A^TP+PA)x = 2x^TPAx = -x^T Qx$. (assuming symmetric $P$). It does **not** follow from this that $2PA = -Q$. This was the subject of my first comment.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, and this has now been said several times.

Comment: @amsmath I see and I'm aware of this. But A only comes in, when I plug plug in for $\dot{x}$. This is what confuses me a little bit. This would contradict the statement, that I can always transpose quadratic forms (termwise).

Comment: @amsmath: I know you know it. I need the OP to see what the issue is.

Comment: @copper.hat Alright, that's fine.:-) I'll leave him/her to you. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of it can be noted that $2\,A^\top P = -Q$ is only correct if $P$ is symmetric. For non-symmetric matrices it would become $A^\top (P + P^\top) = -Q$.

Your approach is valid, however it is more convenient to work with symmetric matrices. Namely:

- matrices are positive definite if their symmetric parts has only positive eigenvalues (this requires less steps if you start with a symmetric matrix).
- For large dimensions symmetric matrices require about only half the memory to store them compared to a non-symmetric matrix.
- For a given $A$ and $Q$ the Laypunov equation $A^\top P + P\,A=-Q$ guarantees to have a positive definite solution for $P$ if $A$ is Hurwitz and $Q$ is positive definite and there a lot of implementations which can solve this. I am not sure if this would also hold for your equation as well.

But if you have found a positive definite $P$ and $Q$ such that $A^\top (P + P^\top) = -Q$ then that would be sufficient to show exponential stability of $\dot{x}=A\,x$.

Comment: I didn't note, that I suppose $P$ to be symmetric because it is used in a quadratic form, hence, only the symmetric part of the matrix is of importance. I'm also familiar with the Lyapunov equation and it's properties. The thing I'm a little bit struggling with is that using a special expression for $\dot{x}$ doesn't allow you to transpose the expression $\dot{x}^TPx$ anymore.

Comment: @vogs what do you mean? Namely $2\,x^\top A^\top P\,x=2\,x^\top P\,A\,x=x^\top (A^\top P+P\,A)x$ if $P$ is symmetric.

Comment: I mean, **without knowing** $\dot{x}=Ax$, I can write $\dot{V}(x)=\dot{x}^TPx+x^TP\dot{x}=2\dot{x}^TPx$ (because I don't know anything about $\dot{x}$). But with the knowledge that $\dot{x}=Ax$, I cannot do this anymore.

Comment: @vogs Why wouldn't you be able to use $\dot{V}(x) = \dot{x}^\top P\,x + x^\top P\,\dot{x} = 2\,\dot{x}^\top P\,x$ when $\dot{x}=A\,x$? Like I stated in my answer, you can, but solving for a positive definite $P$ given a certain $Q$ is less convenient in that case.

Comment: @vogs Namely one can check the negative definiteness of $2\,A^\top P$ or $2\,P\,A$ by looking at the eigenvalues of their symmetric part, which in both cases simplify to $A^\top P + P\,A$.

Comment: For a stable system, $A$ is Hurwitz and $P$ is positive definite (as needed to show stability via the Lyapunov method). This would mean, that $2A^TP=-Q$ is also positive definite. But as I assumed a stable system, I needs to be negativ definite. Hence, there must be a problem somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98186/discussion-between-kwin-van-der-veen-and-vogs).